# Why I can't (push 3 '()) in Common Lisp's REPL?

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I am using Common Lisp and Slime inside Emacs. I have more experience avoiding mutation than using it.

In the REPL I can do:

```
CL-USER> (defvar so-example '())
SO-EXAMPLE

CL-USER> (push 7 so-example)
(7)
```

And it works. However, if I try:

```
CL-USER> (push 7 '())
```

I get an error message saying:

> Undefined function: (SETF QUOTE)

OK. Since `quote` was a problem, I also tried:

```
CL-USER> (push 7 nil)
```

Which also throws an error message:

> NIL is a constant and thus can't be set.

Why does this happen? Why it makes sense?

For me, this is strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modification of literal constants results in undefined behavior in Common Lisp; [from the HyperSpec:](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm)

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified.

This explains the error message observed with `(push 7 nil)`; the same error message would accompany `(push 7 ())`.

The expression `(push 7 '())` is equivalent to `(setf '() (cons 7 '()))`. `setf` expects a [*place*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place), but `(quote ())` is not a place. The `setf` macro is catching the mistake when it realizes that `quote` cannot produce a settable place.

Note that [according to the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm), `push` expects an *item* and a *place* (not a *list*): "*`push` prepends item to the list that is stored in place....*". That is, the *place* is a reference to a list, not the list itself.

Generally speaking, it does not make much sense to attempt to mutate a literal constant like this. Consider doing this with numbers, instead. Attempting to change 7 to 8 by modifying the number 7 is not what we would attempt to do. Instead we would establish a *binding* to 7, and mutate the binding. Doing the same thing with an empty list:

```
CL-USER> (defvar empty-list '())
SO-EXAMPLE
CL-USER> (setf empty-list (cons 7 empty-list))
(7)
```

Here a binding to the empty list is established (`empty-list`), then *the binding* is mutated, binding `empty-list` to a fresh list created by consing `7` to `()`. This is exactly what happened in the first posted example which worked.

```
CL-USER> (defvar so-example '())
SO-EXAMPLE
CL-USER> (push 7 so-example)
(7)
```

A similar example using arithmetic might be:

```
CL-USER> (defvar x 7)
X
CL-USER> (setf x (+ 1 x))
8
CL-USER> x
8
```

Yet you probably would not expect `(setf 7 (+ 1 7))` to do anything good.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for the *macro* `PUSH` says:

```
push item place => new-place-value
```

*Places* are *generalized references*: variables, array slots, structure slots, CLOS object slots, and more. They are documented here: [CLHS 5.1 Generalized Reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_a.htm)

What does *generalized* mean? In Common Lisp *places* are a concept which go beyond simple references like variables or slots. It is even user extensible -> one can defined new types of *places*.

**NIL as a place**

`NIL` (same as `()`) is documented as a **Constant Variable**.

Thus something like this fails:

```
(setf nil 10)
```

`(push 10 nil)` is trying to push `10` to the **place** `NIL`.

```
CL-USER 1 > (macroexpand-1 '(push 10 nil))
(LET ((#:|new-value-1070| 10))
  (LET* ((#:|Store-Var-1069| (CONS #:|new-value-1070| NIL)))
    (SETQ NIL #:|Store-Var-1069|)))
```

There were have it: one tries to set `NIL` (as a reference, here a variable) to the value 10.

Since `NIL` is defined as a **constant variable** and **constant variables** are not to be changed, one can't push something to the place `nil`.

Thus `NIL` is not a useful *place*.

**'NIL as a place**

Why does `(push 10 '())` fail? Which is the same as `(push 10 'nil)` and `(push 10 (quote nil))`.

Again, `push` expects a place. `(quote ...)` is not a defined place.

The default defined places are defined here: [CLHS 5.1.2 Kinds of Places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_ab.htm).

Which makes sense, since `'()` does not reference anything. Remember: *places* are *generalized references*. It is supposed to be a literal object `()`.

**Function CONS**

If we want to add a new object to a list, then we use `cons`:

```
CL-USER 4 > (cons 10 nil)
(10)

CL-USER 5 > (cons 10 'nil)
(10)
```

One than has to use the result list: store it somewhere, pass it to a function, ...

Answer (score 2):

`push` doesn't work with literals as second argument since it is supposed to mutate the place indicated by second argument. The empty list is no place and it cannot be redefined.

`push` is a macro that does different things for different looking second argument. You can check what it does by looking at the `maroexpand-1`:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(push 5 binding))
; ==> (set1 binding (cons 5 binding))

(macroexpand-1 '(push 5 (car structure)))
; ==> (let* ((tmp structure))
;       (rplaca tmp (cons 5 (car tmp))))
```

How it knows what to do is by looking at the `setf` function. eg. calling:

```
(get-setf-expansion 'binding)
; ==> () 
;     ()
;     (tmp)
;     (setq binding tmp)
;     binding
```

You can define your own for eg. a class such that you can `push` elements to an object of a class you have created and make it do something special. Eg. you are extending the language feature of `push` such that it also supports a class you have made.

So what happens when I evaluate `(get-setf-expansion ''())` well you get the reason why the expansion of `(macroexpand-1 '(push 3 '())` turns into:

```
(let* ((tmp (cons 3 '())))
  (funcall #'(setf quote) tmp '()))
```

And there is the source of your unusual error message.